# Cross-compiling linux-->windows: Getting newer OpenGL support with opengl32.dll

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, cross-compiling

I'm using `x86_64-w64-mingw32` toolset, with `gcc` version `4.8.2` to cross-compile 64-bit windows binaries and libraries from my `ubuntu 14.04.1` machine.

I've had no problems cross-compiling and testing my project and various libraries: `SDL2`, `SDL2_image`, `SDL2_mixer`, `SDL2_ttf`, `libfreetype`, `libpng`, `libjpeg`, `libz`, `libvorbis`, `libogg`, `bullet`, `flite`, `polyvox`, `libnoise`.

However, I have issues linking to `OpenGL` when I'm using features that only exist in newer versions of `OpenGL`.

First, let me state a few preconceptions, and please correct me if I'm wrong.

- The `opengl32.a` I'm linking to (in particular, `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libopengl32.a`, that I have from ubuntu package `mingw-w64-x86-64-dev` version `3.1.0-1`) is from the mesa project.
- This `libopengl32.a` targets an `OpenGL` version that seems old. It contains function definition for `glBegin`

  ```
  $ nm /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libopengl32.a | grep ' glBegin$'
   0000000000000000 T glBegin
  ```

  But the same with `glCreateShader` has no matches.

  With the linux library `GL.so`, both have matches:

  ```
  $ readelf -Ws /usr/lib/nvidia-331/libGL.so | grep ' glCreateShader$\|glBegin$'
      2129: 000000000030eaa0     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   17 glCreateShader
      2312: 00000000002fe940     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   17 glBegin
  ```

---

My question is whether or not:

1. I'm just doing things wrong. That for windows, all `OpenGL` > 1.1  function calls have to be dynamically loaded through extensions, and that I've been spoiled by `SDL2/SDL_opengl.h` and/or `GL/glext`. If this is the case, why does `GL.so` have symbols for all the `OpenGL` functions, while `libopengl32.a` does not? And, how do I unify this so that my code becomes unaware of cross-compilation, while using `OpenGL 4.0` functions?
2. I have to cross-compile a newer version of `libopengl32.a` from scratch from the mesa source code. (note: I'm not even sure `libopengl32.a` comes from the mesa project)
3. `???` (something else entirely)

Comment: Use GLEW, or an equivalent.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: In more words. Cross-compile glew (http://glew.sourceforge.net/), and link with this, which should then contain symbols like `glCreateShader`?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Isn't `SDL` supposed to do the job `GLEW` does? And thus an equivalent?

Comment: I think the problem might be that I've been using a combination of `GL` calls through `SDL`, and `GL` calls directly to the graphics drivers. I might have to consider relying on `glew` or similar for the `opengl` then. As I understand it. Hm. I'll investigate.

Comment: SDL does not do the job that GLEW does.  Calls to OpenGL do not go through SDL... they go straight to the OpenGL library.  On Windows, linking directly against the OpenGL library will only give you OpenGL 1.1, so you need a dynamic system that uses `wglGetProcAddress()` to find the function addresses.  See: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions

Answer (score 3):

> If this is the case, why does GL.so have symbols for all the OpenGL functions, while libopengl32.a does not?

Because the developers of the particular implementation in question didn't bother to hide, i.e. not expose the symbols to the outside. The OpenGL operating system ABIs just specify which symbols must be available. They don't specify that additional symbols may not be exposed.

> I have to cross-compile a newer version of libopengl32.a from scratch from the mesa source code. (note: I'm not even sure libopengl32.a comes from the mesa project)

*DON'T DO THIS!* In fact you should never link against a specific version of a OpenGL implementation at all (except if you want to ship that very implementation as a fallback). Always link to some generic interface specification. Never expect anything outside the specified ABIs (not API. ABI = Application Binary Interface) to be exposed. For Windows that's OpenGL-1.1, for Linux at the moment OpenGL-1.2. Anything beyond can be accessed reliable only through the extension mechanism.

> ??? (something else entirely)

You may want to look at glloadgen (https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home), a set of Lua scripts which creates a tightly tailored OpenGL interface loader. With the code generated by `glloadgen` you don't link against `opengl32.lib` `libopen32.a` or `libGL.so` at all. The library is loaded and all symbols resolved at runtime, largely avoiding all the headaches that you get from a mixed loading environment.

Comment: Thanks for this. You definitely cleared up some things for me. I managed to solve my issue by cross-compiling and linking with `glew`. All GL functions calls that went through `SDL` worked without any issue before this. After linking and initializing `glew`, the other GL calls worked fine. By using the same setup that the windows cross-compilation forced me to, I avoid the need (and poor practice) to link to a specific implementation, like I was doing with `NVIDIA`s opengl libraries.

Comment: @swalog: From a historical point of view, that was common practice a very long time ago on Windows; you'd have all sorts of OpenGL "mini drivers" that only implemented enough of OpenGL for a particular piece of hardware to run one or two games. Then around 1999 or so complete ICDs (Installable Client Drivers) finally overtook that archaic practice and from that point on (on Windows anyway) you would go through a single WGL interface to manage all OpenGL extensions. GLX is the equivalent to WGL on Linux, and GLEW hides all of this stuff from you conveniently.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Unfortunately in Linux with the current OpenGL ABI the GLX layer can work as a driver abstraction only if purely indirect rendering contexts are used. For direct rendering the `libGL.so` completely bypasses GLX and the X server and talks directly to the low level driver… and that of course is vendor dependent. Hopefully we'll get rid of that driver model in Linux soon. But it's annoying, because it makes using GPUs of different vendors in the same machine quite a PITA.

Comment: My personal "solution" right now is to use lxc containers to start multiple XDMs and X sessions. Then I either use DMX to join the X sessions into one large screen, or use synergy to synchronize the clipboard and share the mouse/keyboard over the sessions – but synergy is poorly maintained and has a ton of bugs.